# What is the relationship between ratio of vector norms?

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

If a and b are vectors, then is this $\frac{\Vert a \Vert}{\Vert b \Vert} \le \Vert \frac{a}{b}\Vert$ relation true ?
Can it be proved ? ($\Vert \frac{a}{b}\Vert$ is elementwise operation)

Comment: Please note that $\frac{a}{b}$ is not defined when $a,b$ are vectors.

Comment: It's not true because it's not meaningful and not defined.

Comment: I suppose by $\frac{a}{b}$, you mean the element-by-element division right?

Comment: I voted to close this question as "unclear". By know we have two differing interpretations in the answers. I do not think it is useful to add an answer for every new idea what $a/b$ *might* mean. Once it is clarified what is meant I'd consider to reopen it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and yes $\Vert \frac{a}{b}\Vert$  is elementwise operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Division is not defined for vectors. I suppose by $\frac{a}{b}$ you mean element-by-element division. No relationship can be proved.

from Cauchy–Schwarz Inequality we know that  $$\left \| \mathbf{u}.\mathbf{v} \right \|\le\left \| \mathbf{u} \right \|\left \| \mathbf{v} \right \|$$

Put $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{v}=\frac{\mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{b}}$ (meaning that the elements in $\mathbf{v}$ are the multiplicative inverse of the elements in $\mathbf{b}$):

$$\left \| \frac{\mathbf{a}}{\mathbf{b}} \right \|\le\left \| \mathbf{a} \right \|\left \| \frac{\mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{b}} \right \|$$
where $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector whose elements are all $1$. This is the only thing that we can say and no further conclusion can be drawn regarding $\frac{\left \| \mathbf{a} \right \|}{\left \| \mathbf{b} \right \|}$ (based on the explanations below).

We need to compare $\left \| \frac{\mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{b}} \right \|=\sqrt{\sum_i{\frac{1}{b_i^2}}}$ with $\frac{1}{\left \| {\mathbf{b}} \right \|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_i{{b_i^2}}}}$.

From the Jensen's inequality, $\frac{1}{\sum_i{b_i^2}}\le\sum_i{\frac{1}{b_i^2}}$, condidering convexity of $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Hence, $\frac{1}{\left \| {\mathbf{b}} \right \|}\le\left \| \frac{\mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{b}} \right \|$.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of a vector is not defined, so , if $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are vectors the writing $\frac{\vec a}{\vec b}$ has no meaning.

If $\vec a$ is a vector and $b$ is an element of the scalar field than

$$
\frac{||\vec a||}{|b|}=||\frac{1}{b}\vec a ||
$$
by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Definition) of ''norm'' (it is the absolute homogeneity property).